# What is the difference between I will leave in 10 minutes and I’m leaving in 10 minutes?

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference, future-tense

What is the difference between the next sentences?

> 1. I will leave in 10 minutes.

I assume it means: I will leave within 10 min.

> 2. I am leaving in 10 minutes.

I assume it means: I decided to leave after 10 min.

Many thanks!

Comment: This might be related: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/please-to-be-verbing-in-indian-englishs

Answer (score 1):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future-present-continuous-to-talk-about-the-future-i-m-working-tomorrow) provides the following explanation:

> Future: present continuous to talk about the future *(I’m working tomorrow)*
>
> The present continuous can refer to the future. It shows that we have already decided something and usually that we have already made a plan or arrangements:
>
> [talking about plans for a tour by a rock music group]
>
> - *The band is visiting Denmark next May.*
> - *I am taking the train to Paris tomorrow.*
>
> **Warning:** We don’t use the present continuous when we predict something. Instead, we use *going to* or *will*:
>
> - *It’s going to rain again soon.*
> - Not: <strike>*It’s raining again soon.*</strike>

Comment: It's technically referred to (by some) as the ***futurate***.